# MacOS: make pycaffe gives "no rule to make target"

Tags: python, c++, debugging, caffe

I want to import caffe to my python 2.7 (anaconda/mac). I managed to do the make (all, test, and runtest), all passed with success. Here's a snippet of the make runtest command:

```
[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1096 tests from 150 test cases ran. (49316 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1096 tests.
```

The next step according to the [caffe manual](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/interfaces.html) is to run the command:

```
make pycaffee
```

There I get the error:

> make: *** No rule to make target `python/caffe/_caffe.cpp', needed by
>   'python/caffe/_caffe.so'.  Stop.

I believe that this has to do with the **pythonpath**, however I cannot figure out what I am missing.

Here's a piece of my bash_profile:

> export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH" export
>
> PATH="/home/XXX/anaconda/bin:$PATH" export
>
> PYTHONPATH=~/Desktop/Google_deepDream/caffe-master/python:$PYTHONPATH

Also, a piece of my makefile looks like:

```
# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
#PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
#       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's nin root.
 ANACONDA_HOME := ~/../../anaconda
 PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
         $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
         $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include \

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
#PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib
```

I also have all the python dependencies:

```
for req in $(cat requirements.txt); do pip install $req; done
```

Comment: Your bash_profile command that sets `PYTHONPATH` may not be interpreting `~` correctly.  Try echoing `$PYTHONPATH` and see if it has the correct value.  (Although I'm unsure how this would affect `make`.)

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks, but the pythonpath seems correct. After doing echo $PYTHONPATH I get the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment your `MakeFile.config` in a way like `WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1`.

Make sure you have the `_caffe.so` in `caffe_dir/python/caffe`.